# UDP Connection between two PC's (requested address is not valid)

Tags: c#

first - my program works without any problems in a Network with a router. Now I need to establish a connection between two PC's with static IP's, but I get the following message: the requested address is not valid in its context.

Some connect code:

```cs
namespace ConsoleUdpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Socket socketReceiver;
        public static Socket socketSender;
        private const int bufSize = 8 * 1024;
        private static State state = new State();
        private static EndPoint epFrom = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        private static EndPoint epTo = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        private static AsyncCallback recv = null;


        private static string udpBindingIp = "192.168.2.1";
        private static int udpBindingPort = 27000;

        private static string udpOutIp = "self";
        private static int udpOutPort = 0;



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            socketReceiver = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socketReceiver.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            socketReceiver.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(udpBindingIp), udpBindingPort));


            socketSender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socketSender.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            Receive();

            while (true)
            {
                System.Console.ReadKey();
            };

        }

        private static void Send(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                socketSender.Connect(epTo);
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
                socketSender.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, (ar) =>
                {
                    State so = (State)ar.AsyncState;
                    int bytes = socketSender.EndSend(ar);
                }, state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string s = e.Message;
            }
        }

        private static void Receive()
        {
            socketReceiver.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv = (ar) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    State so = (State)ar.AsyncState;
                    int bytes = socketReceiver.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epFrom);
                    socketReceiver.BeginReceiveFrom(so.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv, so);
                    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, bytes);

                    if (udpOutIp.Contains("self"))
                    {
                        epTo = epFrom;
                    }
                    Send(message);

                    if (message.Contains("(") && message.Contains(")"))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("contains ( and )");
                        string command = message.TrimStart();
                        command = command.Substring(0, command.IndexOf("("));
                        string parameters = message.Substring(message.IndexOf("(") + 1, message.IndexOf(")") - message.IndexOf("(")-1);
                        //if (BleCommands.Exists(o => command.Contains(o)))
                        Console.WriteLine(command);
                        Console.WriteLine(parameters);

                    }




                    Console.WriteLine("in: " + message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string s = e.Message;
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + s);
                }

            }, state);
        }

        public class State
        {
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        }
    }



}
```

- Server IP: 192.168.2.1 Subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
- Client IP: 192.168.2.2 Subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
- Ping the Server works without any problems

Comment: What is running on the other side. 192.168.2.1,27000 should this not be 192.168.2.1:27000

Comment: On the other side (192.168.2.2,27001) I run PacketSender for testing

Comment: I try with `var udpBindingIp = "127.0.0.1";`  and `var udpBindingPort = 27000;` no error on `socketReceiver.Bind`. What are your values? what does UdpReceive do?

Comment: Hi, I use var udpBindingIp = 192.168.2.1 and var udpBindingPort = 27000; . I've updated my source above - there you can see a whole demo. Important: it works on a network with a router and on localhost, but not with a direct connection between two PC's with a static IP's.